# Comparing lists, is the subset list within the first list

Tags: python-3.3

How do I write a syntax for something like this?

if our list 1 = ['F', 'W', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'R', 'S']
our second list looks like = ['WINTER']

how would I write that list 1 contains a sequence of strings WINTER?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert both to sets and use `issubset` ?

```
>>> list1
['F', 'W', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'R', 'S']
>>> list2
['W', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'R']
>>> set(list2).issubset(set(list1))
True
```

Or maybe convert them both to sets and then test `list2 - list1` ?

Or (taken [straight from the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html)):

```
{x for x in list2 if x not in list1}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured to use sets. I was wondering whether there was a way to do this using iterations over the list. Currently I am trying to see if I can join the elements in list 1 and then compare but there is excess letters within that joint which I don't know how to remove other manually removing each one from the list and checking. Is there a way just to use iterations and lists?